How to run pact-broker as a windows service in windows server
We want to run pact broker in windows server and we able to start the broker but when the server restart/logoff the pact broker also getting disconnected and we manually need to start the broker again.
Do we have any option to run the pact broker as windows service so it will always startup when the server restart or logon.

Maybe you can just add some script which will check and start it, on every log on and add it into task scheduler, with set trigger "At log on"

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
